# Explicit destructor call with decltype

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct Foo {};

int main()
{
   Foo f;
   f.~decltype(f)(); // fine with clang, error with gcc
   f.~decltype(auto)(); // error with both clang and gcc 
}
```

The rules for an explicit destructor call are handled by the standard grammar with `pseudo-destructor-name` which is defined as follows:

> pseudo-destructor-name:
>       nested-name-specifier opt  type-name :: ~ type-name 
>       nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id :: ~type-name 
>       ~ type-name 
>       ~ decltype-specifier

And:

> decltype-specifier:   
>   decltype ( expression )  
>   decltype ( auto )

Then shouldn't the above snippet be well-formed as per standard? (Not considering the fact that the destructor is called twice and then a third time on the same object.)

[GCC Live](https://godbolt.org/g/3DMMuF) 
[Clang Live](https://godbolt.org/g/LsJEMR)

Comment: What should it do if it was well-formed?

Comment: @underscore_d It should call the destructor? The example is not an actual program.

Comment: Not that it would matter, but in your case, the grammar to use is not "pseudo-destructor-name", but unqualified-id (of the form "~ decltype-specifier") and "postfix-expression ( ... )" where the postfix-expression is "f.<unqualified-id>". The production pseudo-destructor-name is only used when the type isn't of class-type or when it's a dependent type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed.
**§7.1.6.4/[dcl.spec.auto]** states:

> A program that uses `auto` or `decltype(auto)` in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.

There, I cannot find anything that should allow you to write this. Generally, `decltype(auto)` is used in variable and function declarations only. The fact the grammar allows is doesn't mean it's well-formed, though.

Therefore, writing something like `f.~decltype(f)()` hasn't been explicitely forbidden and is allowed as stated in the grammar. The fact that the GCC won't compile it is most likely a bug.

Comment: Then what do you think about f.~decltype(f)(). clang allows it, gcc doesn't. Is it gcc's fault?

Comment: `decltype(f)` is not `decltype(auto)`. It's `decltype(auto)` that your question is asking about and that Jodocus has answered about. Why shouldn't `decltype(f)` work here? It's not very useful, but it *is* unambiguous and has no reason to be disallowed.

Comment: @underscore_d No, my question asks about both, hence why both are present in the code snippet. I think the answer answers half my question.

Comment: If even `f.~decltype(f)()` isn't allowed, then how can a *decltype-specifier* even be used here? ...

Comment: This construct seems to be described under [Unqualified Identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Unqualified_identifiers): `the character ~ followed by a decltype specifier, such as ~decltype(str).
(since C++11)`  Trying to understand that brought me here.