# Provide default arguments for subscript operator and function call operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, language-lawyer, default-arguments

In the following code, I have provided **default arguments** for **array subscript operator**.

```
struct st 
{
    int operator[](int x = 0)
    {
        // code here
    }
};
```

But, compiler generated an error :

```
error: 'int st::operator[](int)' cannot have default arguments
     int operator[](int x = 0)
```

But, If I provide default arguments for **function call** operator.

```
struct st 
{
    int operator()(int x = 0)
    {
        // code here
    }
};
```

It's working fine.

So, I have a questions:

- Why doesn't allowed default arguments for the array subscript operator?
- Why does allowed default arguments for the function call operator?

Comment: Because function calls can have any number of arguments, while array subscripting always has one.

Comment: I can't imagine any use for a "default subscript".

Comment: What would `x[]` mean in this case?

Comment: @molbdnilo: A default subscript would make `some_array[]` a valid expression, and might allow for something like PHP's `$array[] = 'a new value tacked on to the end';`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard states it quite clearly.

The default arguments are not allowed in [operator overloading](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#8) of [subscripting operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#over.sub-1).

> An operator function cannot have default arguments, except where explicitly stated below. Operator functions cannot have more or fewer parameters than the number required for the corresponding operator, as described in the rest of this subclause.

and

> `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.

While for [function call operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#over.call-1)

> `operator()` shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters. It can have default arguments.

Overloaded operators try to follow the same behavior of the built-in ones; with the built-in subscript operator the (only one) index is always required, it doesn't have *default arguments*. Then the overloaded operator is not allowed to have default arguments either. On the other hand, functions are always fine to take arbitrary number of parameters and have default arguments.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. It gives an explicit statement from the standard which always outranks grammar specifications.

Comment: @Jodocus The grammar specifications come to the same conclusion certainly. It's just lucky there're such clear statements in the standard.

Comment: That's true. But consider the reverse case where the grammar allows something that gets prohibited explicitely in the standard. Those cases exist and give a hard reason on why explicit statements are always stronger than grammar statements.

Comment: @Jodocus *"explicit statements are always stronger than grammar statements"* - does it say that somewhere in the Standard?  I've never noticed it before.  Sounds like it'd be an ambiguity until formally rectified.

Comment: @Jodocus Agreed. But the statements might be confusing and vague; in this respect I think grammar specifications win at last.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I haven't found anything like that in the standard. But there are many examples where grammar and standard contradict with the latter winning. Take for example [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910844/explicit-destructor-call-with-decltype/46911517#46911517) where my answer led to the same conclusion.

Comment: @Jodocus: I see.  I'm not sure your notion of "winning" is the most useful here - what a particular compiler does for an ambiguous part of the Standard doesn't tell you much about what another compiler might do.  Where there's ambiguity, you can't trust all compiler vendors to spot it and give preference to the non-grammar stipulations: the ambiguity will be raised as a defect and advice given on how it should be handled.

Answer (score 13):

> - Why doesn't allowed default argument for array subscript operator?
> - Why does allowed default argument for function call operator?

Mainly because the C++ grammar says so. According to A.4 [gram.expr]:

> ```
> postfix-expression --> postfix-expression [ expr-or-braced-init-list ] 
>                    --> postfix-expression ( expression-list opt ) 
>                    --> simple-type-specifier (expression-list opt) 
>                    --> typename-specifier ( expression-list opt )
> ```

The parameters for braces are optional, the ones for brackets not.
As suggested in the comment, note that brackets are required to take exactly *one* parameter whereas the braces can take an arbitrary number of parameters.

Also consider songyuanyao's answer for an explicit statement from the standard.

Comment: This answer is great. It might be improved by noting that `[]` must take exactly 1 parameter, no more no less, in clearer to read english.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are really asking *why* the standard allows one and not the other. The **reason is mainly to do with what people expect**, rather than some technical logic that precludes a default in one case but not the other:

It's a matter of what people expect the [] operator to mean. Normally it means "Get the element at [...]" where we use an int or some other type to make a specific query about a member of a collection. We are always interested in asking about a specific member, and we always have a specific query in mind.

Now consider what a default argument means. Often it means "you can specify this, but if not I'll assume this default". This works great for certain functions, and people are used to it.

Changing this would probably make a lot of people scratch their heads when they see `int x = vec[]`

Answer (score 1):

The operators (both overloading of user-defined-types and for inbuilt types) are intended to let people use notations familiar from mathematics, logic and general usage (though `<<` and `>>` have seen double-service as streaming operators, and notational compromises had to be made given the limited characters near-universally available on computers).  To turn around and allow variations on the intuitive, familiar notations (such as implied arguments) seems counter-productive.

`operator()` is different though in that it's there to abstract away differences between "calling" (through) an object and calling a hard-coded function - it needs to support default arguments to do that properly.